# Git: decorate all commits displayed by "git log --all" with branch names

Tags: git

Firstly, `git log --graph --oneline --decorate` is not what I want to do.

---

Oftentimes I run `git log -p --all -G pattern` and I wish I could see branch names on which the changes have been made. Are there any ways to do that?

This might be an ill-posed question because, from what I understand, Git doesn't explicitly record the name of the branch on which a commit was made, and when we have multiple branches we cannot uniquely associate, say, the first branch in the repo with them.

Comment: You might be able to make use of `git branch --contains`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can customize `--pretty-format` to set color, swap output values etc.

```
$ git log -p --all -G pattern --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset%n' --branches
```

By this command, you can see `commit-hash`, `branch-name`, `commit-message`, `time`, `committer-name` and `changes of the commits`.

Answer (score 0):

> This might be an ill-posed question because, from what I understand, Git doesn't explicitly record the name of the branch on which a commit was made, and when we have multiple branches we cannot uniquely associate, say, the first branch in the repo with them.

That's correct.

The fundamental problem is that the branch *name*, if there is one at all—there may be none, if you are in "detached HEAD" mode for instance—is not part of the commit.  Moreover, branch names can be added, changed, and removed at any time *after* the commit, so that any given commit can be on no, one, or many branches, *and* the set of containing branches changes dynamically.

This is in sharp contrast to most version control systems.  For instance, in Mercurial, the name of the branch on which a commit is made *is* part of the commit.  That commit is forevermore on that branch, and it is never on any other branch.  Every commit is on exactly one branch and it is easy to turn a commit ID into a branch name.  In Git, a commit is on zero or more branches, and when it is on many branches, it is on all of them simultaneously.

Thus, in Git, branch names—and for that matter, tag names and all other references, including `HEAD` itself—are essentially irrelevant, except for one critical point: references are how we (and Git) gain *entry* to the commit graph.  The identity of each commit—each Git object, actually—is its big ugly SHA-1 hash.  That unique ID locates the object within the repository.  References—branch and tag names, mostly—get us started in the graph, and then each commit has a reference to its parent, or multiple references to its multiple parents, by their raw IDs.

As [Schwern noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41302219/git-decorate-all-commits-displayed-by-git-log-all-with-branch-names#comment69806848_41302219), `git branch --contains` will find the names by which some Git object is reachable.  Git's `log` has the `%d` and `%D` formats, which do what `--decorate` does, but they will only show which references point *directly to* the commit being displayed, while `-G regex` selects only commits that add or remove a line matching the given *regex*.<sup>1</sup>  So if you have a graph fragment like this:

```
...-o--o--*--o   <-- branch1
     \
      o--o--*    <-- branch2
```

where the two commits marked `*` get selected by the `-G` pattern argument, the commit at the tip of `branch2` will be decorated (because `refs/heads/branch2` names that commit) but the commit one step back from the tip of `branch1` will not (because no branch points directly to it).

(If there is a tag, whether lightweight or annotated, pointing to the `*` commit reachable from `branch1`, `%d` would display that tag's name.)

Many Git commands walk the commit graph—mostly by invoking `git rev-list`, or by having `git rev-list` built in (e.g., `git log` and `git rev-list` are built from the same C source file, which has two different `main`-like functions, chosen based on whether we want just the hashes, i.e., `rev-list`, or to produce human-readable text, i.e., `log`).  The entry points into the graph are usually `HEAD` and/or some branch and/or tag names.  The `--all` option means "all references": all branch and tag names, the `refs/stash` reference, everything under `refs/notes`, and so on.

---

<sup>1</sup>To do this, `git log` / `git rev-list` must diff each commit against its parent.  This is problematic for merge commits, which have multiple parents.  The precise details of how this works are quite obscure, but it's worth pointing out that merge commits mess with the history simplification code, and you may want both `--full-history` to disable side-branch pruning, and `-m` to split merge commits so that an *N*-parent merge produces *N* separate diffs, one against each parent, so that the split-apart merge can itself be selected if any one such diff contains that expression.